# Passing a parameter to main method of a class

Tags: python

How can I pass a parameter to `__main__` method?

Suppose I have the following class resides in a file `base.py`:

## base.py

```
class Base(object):
    var_text = ""
    def do_something(self):
       pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (var_text)
```

Now, I have a file `child.py` where I want to pass `var_text` to main method in `base.py`. How do I do that?

## child.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def test(self):
   b = Base()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `base()` start with an uppercase?

Comment: Oops! I am sorry , typo mistake. Will be modified

Comment: None of the code you've shown has a "`__main__` method."

Comment: @PedroKali: furthermore it is not clear where you define `var_text` in your `base.py`. The definition is missing.

Comment: `__main__` is not method. It's string.

Comment: My apology. I am a Java programmer and just learning Python. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you mean command line arguments passed to the script? You can access by using sys module. `sys.argv[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

With [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) you can do it as such

```
class Base(object):
    var_text = "hello"
    def do_something(self):
       pass

class Child(Base):
    pass

child = Child()

print child.var_text
```